# how to setup subversion using svn?

Tags: wordpress, svn, tortoisesvn

i have a hosting where i put my domains files. i have one directory called `wordpress` where i installed a copy of wp. What i am trying to do is to do an SVN checkout on that folder.

but i get: `Redirect cycle detected for URL '....`

any ideas how to set it up so that i can grab those files on my computer and then checking them in after i make changes?

also, im not looking necessarily for something specific on wordpress, i might want to check out some other files lather on

thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do?  Is the SVN repository hosted on the machine you are refering to?  Where is the svn repo, and where are you trying to checkout your working copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the folder you are trying to "checkout" is an actual SVN repository. 
You can do so with the `svnadmin create` command. More info available [here](http://systhread.net/texts/200607subver.php)